# How I can test the openDrawer with enzyme in React Native?

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-navigation, enzyme

I'm having some trouble with my tests in react native. I'm using enzyme and I'm trying to click in a button that open a drawer. I'm using react navigation as well, however when I try this problem happens:

TypeError: navigation.openDrawer is not a funciton

```
  const props = {
    navigation: {
      openDrawer: jest.fn(),
    },
  };

  const wrapper = shallow(<HeaderButton {...props} />);

  it('DrawerMenu is Called', () => {
    expect(
      wrapper
        .find('AnimatedComponent')
        .props()
        .onPress(),
    ).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

const HeaderButton = (navigation: NavigationParams) => (
  <TouchableRipple
    onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
  >
    <Icon
      name="menu"
      size={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 20 : 24}
      color="white"
      style={{ marginHorizontal: 16 }}
    />
  </TouchableRipple>
);
```

[Link to code: https://gist.github.com/salomaoluiz/dd710b3506b95b3f0f13410a02ef41cf]

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is that `HeaderButton` should take `props` (which has `navigation` as a property), rather than `navigation` directly.

This should work:
`const HeaderButton = ({ navigation }) => (`

Or, if you prefer:

```
const HeaderButton = (props) => (
  <TouchableRipple
    onPress={props.navigation.openDrawer}
  >
```